# For which groups do there exist a matrix representation which for all elements are (anti-)symmetric?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm wondering if there is some general way to make matrix representations of group elements which are individually either symmetric (or anti-symmetric) or if that will only work for some groups. I.e. if for all representation matrices $M_i \in (A\cup S)$, where $A$ is set of antisymmetric matrices and $S$ set of symmetric matrices.

The reason I would like to do this is because I think it may be practically convenient when making calculations. If it is possible would it mean we would need to build larger matrices or some other penalty in some sense except to if we did not have the requirement for them to be symmetric (or anti symmetric).

Comment: The identity matrix is not anti symmetric, so that case is never possible.

Comment: But it is symmetric. Maybe I should reformulate the question.

Comment: note also that multplication of two symmetric matrices might not be symmetric. They are iff they commutes.

Comment: Let $V$ be a $G$ modulue than if you take ortagonal base $B$ for $V$, then $[g]_B$ is always unitary matrix.

Comment: But a product between a symmetric and an antisymmetric matrix?